# Fields Requested Limits Media Types Returned in Instagram Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

Is this a bug or by design?

With the new **Instagram Graph API**, if you ask for a field that only some media types have (i.e. [children](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/#metadata) or [thumbnail_url](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/#metadata)), the overall results are restricted to only media of that type.

For example, the request below will return 21 results of varying types:

```
GET graph.facebook.com/.../tags?fields=media_id
```

But the following returns 5 where all 5 are of media_type='CAROUSEL_ALBUM':

```
GET graph.facebook.com/.../tags?fields=media_id,children{media_type,media_url}
```

The `limit` parameter has no impact on this behaviour.

Is there an efficient way to get everything (all media types) in a single call and still have conditional fields like [children](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/#metadata) or [thumbnail_url](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/#metadata) populated?

Doesn't this behavior, which also impacts GETs for individual media by id, effectively eliminate any bulk retrieval possibilities that involve multiple IDs across mix types?

Comment: what happens when you pass `&limit=50`?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I will likely create a job for each media_type == "CAROUSEL_ALBUM" and then fetch them in separate requests.

Comment: I created a bug report to check if this is by design, or a bug. You can follow it here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/156763381702839/